# Computing area/ space of intersection between a pair of Beta distribution/ Dirichlet distributions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, numerical-methods

I need to compute the area/ space of intersection between a pair of Beta distribution/ Dirichlet distributions. As I am a non mathematics guy, it will be great if someone helps me out with the expression for the enclosed area by a pair of (Dirichlet/ Beta) distribution curves.

Also is there any easy to implement numeric method for this?